# sortable list to checkbox list JQuery with minimal code change

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Currently i have a list of sortable elements with a text:

[image: Current look and feel]

How can i change it to a list of checkboxes with labels with the least code change?

[image: Ideal look and feel]

**Current Code:**

```
<div class='left'>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
     $(function() {
         $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
           items: "li:not(.ui-state-highlight)",
           placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
         });
         $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
     });
   </script>
```

Javascript

```
 var nodes = document.getElementById('sortable').getElementsByClassName('ui-state-highlight');  
      if (nodes.length > 0)
      {
        nodes[0].innerHTML = getSymbol();
        nodes[0].setAttribute("class", "ui-state-default");
      }
```

Comment: please provide details for your downvotes, i'm just trying to learn

Comment: While I haven't downvoted you, I believe it was a result of the very limited info you provided to the problem. When you say "checkbox list", what does that mean? Do you still want the checkboxes to be sortable? Or just a unordered list of checkboxes? What do you mean by "with the least code change"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
        });
    });

function addCheckbox(name) {
       var container = $('#cblist');
       var inputs = container.find('input');
       var id = inputs.length+1;

       var html = '<input type="checkbox" class="keepSymbol" id="cb'+id+'" value="'+name+'" onclick="checkboxClick(this)" checked="true" /> <label for="cb'+id+'">'+name+'</label>';
       container.append($(html));
    }
    </script>
```

Javscript

```
 var nodes = document.getElementById('cblist').getElementsByClassName('keepSymbol');
      if (nodes.length > 0)
      {
        addCheckbox(getSymbol());
      }
      else
      {
        return; // no more space
      }
```

This could be a good example, you have to play around with it to get what you need.